# Using bootstrap - change a column to a row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a layout which includes a row with 3 columns. Each column has 3 items listed vertically. I'm using Bootstrap.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 ">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200">
      <h3>SOMETHING</h3>
      <div class="url"> https://something.com </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200">
      <h3>NOTHING</h3>
      <div class="url"> https://nothing.com/</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 appcontainer">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200">
      <h3>EVERYTHING</h3>
      <div class="url"> https://everything.com/</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When the row collapses at 767 px down to about 400 px the layout feels wrong as the individual columns don't fill the space very well. In that case I would like to have it displayed with the image on the left and the header and url on the right *as though* it were like this..

```
<div class="col-sm-4 ">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <h3>SOMETHING</h3>
          <div class="url"> https://something.com </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can this be accomplished with css and media queries? Or do I have to dig into some javascript?

It fells like I should be able set something up using display, but I haven't found a magic combination that does anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the result:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .col-xs-6 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.row {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
          <h3>SOMETHING</h3>
          <div class="url"> https://something.com </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
          <h3>NOTHING</h3>
          <div class="url"> https://nothing.com </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
          <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-12">
          <h3>EVERYTHING</h3>
          <div class="url"> https://everything.com </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it's a very nice solution and works perfectly in your example but doesn't switch back at 400px in my actual code. Must have a typo somewhere.

Comment: Also, how does one set up a code example so it works the way you've done here?

Comment: @marcp Can you give me a link to your actual page?

Comment: @marcp The code `@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .col-xs-6 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}`   should have to go after the link to bootstrap.css.

Comment: I tried setting up a jsfiddle but it works properly there with the exact same code!

Comment: I'm calling bootstrap in the head section of my html. Should it be in the css instead?

Comment: @marcp I think the key is in the order of style definitions. 1) Link to bootstrap.css. 2) Override it for ourselves.